# IOS Searching Keyboard Slow

Tags: ios, keyboard, uisearchbar

Hi i have a live search in my app that searches and displays the results at the same time, it all works great but the keyboard just look's a bit laggy.

is there a way i can make the keyboard not lag and still do a live search.

this is where the search reload the search result:

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{

[self filterListForSearchText:searchString scope:
[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

return YES;

}
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you search the entire table dictionary, you can search try searching it on a separate thread with [`performSelectorInBackground:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorInBackground%3awithObject%3a).

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:filterListForSearchText withObject:searchString scope:
[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
```

When you need to update the table UI, you can switch back the main thread with `performSelectorOnMainThread:`.

example: `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:updateTableMethod];`

If you don't need to support older iOS versions than 4.0, you can also try [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html).

If searching in the background is not working, the table is trying to load too many rows at once. You may want to have it only load a certain amount of rows and load more as the user scrolls down.

Comment: I have tried to do it in the background but no luck, the keyboard was running very good but my data display was not displaying properly, so i think i may have to just go with your last option, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @AnsonL for the options, really helped.

this is what i ended up with, if anyone wanted to know:

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.yourdomain.yourappname", NULL);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    //code to be executed in the background

    [self filterListForSearchText:searchString scope:
[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //code to be executed on the main thread when background task is finished
        [searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];

    });
});

return NO;

}
```